# Where to include License

Tags: fancybox-3

We have purchased Fancybox license. Now how to I add license to the library on our site page? The page is already working without providing license. Does a license needs to be added in library when loading on site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not worry, you do not need to include/use it anywhere, just keep it.